# Oracle ORA-12704 with case expression on CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle update statement with a case that is trying to either set or ignore a value (leave original value the same ).

With this code, either of the two individual sets compile on their own ( the two commented out ones ).
But when combined in a case statement, I get "PL/SQL: ORA-12704: character set mismatch"
The column is a CLOB column.

Alternatively is there a way to conditionally not do a set in an update statement?

```
         LONGDESCRIPT = ( CASE v_CanUpdateAssetDescription WHEN 1 THEN p_description ELSE LONGDESCRIPT END ), 
         -- LONGDESCRIPT = LONGDESCRIPT,
         --LONGDESCRIPT = p_description,
```

Comment: What are the types of `v_CanUpdateAssetDescription` and `p_description`?

Comment: That's a case _expression_.

Comment: Are you updating other columns in the same query?

Comment: Yes updating other columns.  `v_CanUpdateAssetDescription` is number(10).
`p_description CLOB default null`.  Oddly, it is LONGDESCRIPT = LONGDESCRIPT that seems to have the problem in the case expression.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the character set of `p_description` is not the same as that of `LONGDESCRIPT`. In a simple assignment Oracle can work with this, but in a CASE expression all values returned from the different paths through the CASE expression must be of exactly the same type. As it appears you're doing this in PL/SQL you might try doing something like the following:

```
DECLARE
  cCLOB_var  YOUR_TABLE.LONGDESCRIPT%TYPE;
BEGIN
  cCLOB_var := p_description;

  UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
    SET LONGDESCRIPT = CASE v_CanUpdateAssetDescription
                         WHEN 1 THEN cCLOB_var
                         ELSE LONGDESCRIPT
                       END
    ...etc...
END;
```

You might also try using a CAST:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
    SET LONGDESCRIPT = CASE v_CanUpdateAssetDescription
                         WHEN 1 THEN CAST(p_description AS YOUR_TABLE.LONGDESCRIPT%TYPE)
                         ELSE LONGDESCRIPT
                       END
```

Not sure if the latter will work or not, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly I found that to_clob did the trick.
And even more oddly, I only needed TO_CLOB for the LONGDESCRIPT value.

```
LONGDESCRIPT = ( CASE v_CanUpdateAssetDescription WHEN 1 THEN p_description ELSE to_clob(LONGDESCRIPT) END ),
```